# selective count in a group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I'm trying to make a report about the state of our clubs and their teams for the current season. A club can have many teams and each team has season-specific information (like image_url) in the table season_team.

I want to know how many teams already entered any season-specific information and how many uploaded an image. Following SQL is incorrect SQL, but maybe my intention comes across:

```
SELECT
    t.club_id,
    count(distinct t.id)                          as team_count,
    count(st.id) WHERE st.id IS NOT null          as season_team_count,
    count(st.id) WHERE st.image_url IS NOT null   as teams_with_image,
    count(st.id) WHERE st.state = 'APPROVED'      as approved_teams,
    count(st.id) WHERE st.state = 'REJECTED'      as rejected_teams
FROM
    team t
        LEFT OUTER JOIN season_team st ON (st.team_id = t.id and st.season_id = 8)
GROUP BY
    t.club_id
```

can anyone point me in the right direction how to do this best?

I know I can do a dirty trick by just doing a "count(distinct st.image_url) -1" to get all the different images and substract 1 for the null entry. But that wouldn't work for the approved_teams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FILTER`:

```
SELECT t.club_id,
       count(distinct t.id)                          as team_count,
       count(st.id) FILTER (WHERE st.id IS NOT null)          as season_team_count,
       count(st.id) FILTER (WHERE st.image_url IS NOT null)   as teams_with_image,
       count(st.id) FILTER (WHERE st.state = 'APPROVED')      as approved_teams,
       count(st.id) FILTER (WHERE st.state = 'REJECTED')      as rejected_teams
FROM team t LEFT OUTER JOIN
     season_team st
     ON st.team_id = t.id and st.season_id = 8
GROUP BY t.club_id
```

Comment: awesome! ...and also amazing how close I was with just guessing :-)